# convert ajax actionlink as a bootstrap button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

i have an ajax actionlink like this:

```
 <div style="float:left"> @Ajax.ActionLink("EMPLOYEE", "_PartialEmployeeIndex", "Employee", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "divToUpdate" }) </div>
```

i usually use bootstrap to style my buttons like this:

```
  <input class="btn btn-info" type="button" value="Input">
```

or like this

```
 <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"> </button>
```

so how can i convert an ajax action link to a bootstrap button?

i dont want to put a class name to the div containing the ajax actionlink because the button is displayed with black color font and with an underline...

i want it to be displayed as an actual button with no underline and with white font

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be able to use the [htmlAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470546.aspx) parameter to add whatever Bootstrap class you want:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("EMPLOYEE", "_PartialEmployeeIndex", "Employee", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "divToUpdate" }, new { @class = "btn" })
```

Comment: But what if I want to have a span/icon included in that button?

Answer (score 7):

If you only want an icon you can do it as:

```
    @Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "Delete", new { id = 1 }, new AjaxOptions
                                        {
                                            Confirm = "Are you sure you wish to delete?",
                                            HttpMethod = "Delete",
                                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                            LoadingElementId = "div_loading"
                                        }, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash" })
```

- The name ationlink cannot be null or empty, so i recommended an space.

Comment: Boom.  You win.  The space is everything.  Not a button, but good enough.

Answer (score 5):

If you want an actual Ajax `button` element, rather than a styling hack, it is also possible but a little involved. It is a shame that MS has not yet chosen to add an ActionButton to both the Html and Ajax helpers as the differences are actually very minor when you remove the duplication of private support methods (you would only need the `ActionButton` and `GenerateButton` methods shown below).

The end result is you can have real buttons that trigger like ajax action links:

### e.g.

```
@Ajax.ActionButton("Delete", "Delete", "document", 
     new { id = ViewBag.Id }, 
     new AjaxOptions() 
     { 
         Confirm="Do you really want to delete this file?", 
         HttpMethod = "Get", 
         UpdateTargetId = "documentlist" }, 
         new { id = "RefreshDocuments" 
     })
```

### 1. Create an AjaxHelper extension

The code below is based on a decompile of the AjaxExtensions class as many of the required helper methods are not exposed on HtmlHelper.

```
public static partial class AjaxExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString ActionButton(this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper, string buttonText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValuesBlah, AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, object htmlAttributesBlah)
    {
        // Convert generic objects to specific collections
        RouteValueDictionary routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(routeValuesBlah);
        RouteValueDictionary htmlAttributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributesBlah);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(buttonText))
            throw new ArgumentException("Button text must be provided");
        string targetUrl = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl((string)null, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, ajaxHelper.RouteCollection, ajaxHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, true);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(GenerateButton(ajaxHelper, buttonText, targetUrl, AjaxExtensions.GetAjaxOptions(ajaxOptions), htmlAttributes));
    }

    public static string GenerateButton(AjaxHelper ajaxHelper, string linkText, string targetUrl, AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("input");
        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", linkText);
        tagBuilder.MergeAttributes<string, object>(htmlAttributes);
        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", targetUrl);
        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("type", "button");
        if (ajaxHelper.ViewContext.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled)
            tagBuilder.MergeAttributes<string, object>(ajaxOptions.ToUnobtrusiveHtmlAttributes());
        else
            tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("onclick", AjaxExtensions.GenerateAjaxScript(ajaxOptions, "Sys.Mvc.AsyncHyperlink.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), {0});"));
        return tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
    }

    private static string GenerateAjaxScript(AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, string scriptFormat)
    {
        string str = ajaxOptions.ToJavascriptString();
        return string.Format((IFormatProvider)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, scriptFormat, new object[1] { str });
    }

    private static AjaxOptions GetAjaxOptions(AjaxOptions ajaxOptions)
    {
        if (ajaxOptions == null)
            return new AjaxOptions();
        else
            return ajaxOptions;
    }

    public static string ToJavascriptString(this AjaxOptions ajaxOptions)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("{");
        stringBuilder.Append(string.Format((IFormatProvider)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, " insertionMode: {0},", new object[1]
        {
             ajaxOptions.InsertionModeString()
        }));
        stringBuilder.Append(ajaxOptions.PropertyStringIfSpecified("confirm", ajaxOptions.Confirm));
        stringBuilder.Append(ajaxOptions.PropertyStringIfSpecified("httpMethod", ajaxOptions.HttpMethod));
        stringBuilder.Append(ajaxOptions.PropertyStringIfSpecified("loadingElementId", ajaxOptions.LoadingElementId));
        stringBuilder.Append(ajaxOptions.PropertyStringIfSpecified("updateTargetId", ajaxOptions.UpdateTargetId));
        stringBuilder.Append(ajaxOptions.PropertyStringIfSpecified("url", ajaxOptions.Url));
        stringBuilder.Append(ajaxOptions.EventStringIfSpecified("onBegin", ajaxOptions.OnBegin));
        stringBuilder.Append(ajaxOptions.EventStringIfSpecified("onComplete", ajaxOptions.OnComplete));
        stringBuilder.Append(ajaxOptions.EventStringIfSpecified("onFailure", ajaxOptions.OnFailure));
        stringBuilder.Append(ajaxOptions.EventStringIfSpecified("onSuccess", ajaxOptions.OnSuccess));
        --stringBuilder.Length;
        stringBuilder.Append(" }");
        return ((object)stringBuilder).ToString();
    }

    public static string InsertionModeString(this AjaxOptions ajaxOptions)
    {
        switch (ajaxOptions.InsertionMode)
        {
            case InsertionMode.Replace:
                return "Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace";
            case InsertionMode.InsertBefore:
                return "Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.insertBefore";
            case InsertionMode.InsertAfter:
                return "Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.insertAfter";
            default:
                return ((int)ajaxOptions.InsertionMode).ToString((IFormatProvider)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }

    public static string EventStringIfSpecified(this AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, string propertyName, string handler)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(handler))
            return string.Empty;
        return string.Format((IFormatProvider)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, " {0}: Function.createDelegate(this, {1}),",
            new object[2]
              {
                propertyName,
                handler
              });
    }

    public static string PropertyStringIfSpecified(this AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, string propertyName, string propertyValue)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyValue))
            return string.Empty;
        string str = propertyValue.Replace("'", "\\'");
        return string.Format((IFormatProvider)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, " {0}: '{1}',",
            new object[2]
              {
                propertyName,
                str
              });
    }
}
```

### 2. Modify jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

Only a small change is required to the JQuery of jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js to accept the new button object, as it is very close to begin with. First the selector needs to accept buttons as well as links and then the href needs to come from an attribute so than a non-link can provide it (not strictly browser compliant but works for now).

```
$(document).on("click", "input[data-ajax=true],a[data-ajax=true]", function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        asyncRequest(this, {
            url: $(this).attr("href"),
            type: "GET",
            data: []
        });
    });
```

*Note: this is using the latest version of everything as at the date of answering (MVC 5)

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to worry about assigning proper classes to every Bootstrap element, check out [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/)

In the example with your ajax link you'd write something like this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("EMPLOYEE", "_PartialEmployeeIndex", "Employee", ).AjaxOptions(new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "divToUpdate" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Terry answer, if you want to add html to the button, the best way is to use Javascript to append the html code. The linkText parameter of Ajax.Actionlink automatically encodes any text you provide and there is nothing you can do to avoid that (except writing your own helper).

Something like JQuery append or prepend would work.

```
<div> 
@Ajax.ActionLink("EMPLOYEE", "_PartialEmployeeIndex", "Employee", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "divToUpdate" }, new { @class = "btn btn-default my-custom-class" }) 
</div>

<script>
    $(".my-custom-class").prepend("<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\"></span>&nbsp; ");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use Ajax.BeginForm, which allows you to enter HTML directly. This assumes that you're not already in a form.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EMPLOYEE", "_PartialEmployeeIndex", "Employee", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "divToUpdate" }))
{
    <button type="submit" id="EmployeeButton" title="Employee" aria-label="Employee Button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
    </button>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "EditUser/" + Model.Id, null, new AjaxOptions { 
      OnSuccess = "userEditGet", 
      HttpMethod = "post", 
      LoadingElementId = "ajaxLoader" }
 ,new { @class = "btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-edit" })
```